# Find from database table based on field value of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two database tables: a `pages` table to store page IDs and other meta data, and a `pages_revisions` table that stores revisions of a page's title and content.

In my application I have a core `Pages` controller. I want to modify this controller so it's passed a page title, and the controller then returns a database record if a page whose latest revision title matches.

So far, I had this:

```
SELECT
    id, (
        SELECT title
        FROM pages_revisions
        WHERE page_id = pages.id
        ORDER BY created DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS title, (
        SELECT content
        FROM pages_revisions
        WHERE page_id = pages.id
        ORDER BY created DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS content
    FROM pages
```

But with this query I can't then use the aliased `title` column to perform a `WHERE` query; for example `...WHERE title = 'Home'`.

How can I modify the above query to select pages (with its latest title) and then filter those results?

Comment: `But with this query I can then`, do you mean `can't`?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*In this answer I'll refactor the query to avoid the problem altogether.*)

You could, instead, use a correlated sub-query in the JOINs to find the records you want...
(This one assumes page_revisions has it's own unique identifier)

```
SELECT
  pages.id,
  page_revisions.title,
  page_revisions.content
FROM
  pages
LEFT JOIN
  page_revisions
    ON page_revisions.id = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM page_revisions WHERE page_id = pages.id ORDER BY created DESC)
WHERE
  <conditions>
```

Answer (score 0):

(*I'll answer the idea in this question; referencing complex calculations in the WHERE clause, from the SELECT statements.  I won't refactor the query, even though I possibly would in a real-world scenario.*)

If you want to use a value from a correlated sub-query, you can wrap the whole query in another query...
*(Note, most omptimisers will understand this and not waste time on pointless results.)*

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  your-query
)
  AS data
WHERE
  <conditions>
```